# How to include separator when array split?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I want to split some string with regexp.
But I can't get the result what I think.
I heard javascript does not support lookbehind.

`var str = "always on the go? if yes, slip-on this dress that comes with u-        neck, long sleeves and loose fit. wear with slacks and beanie to finish the ensemble.↵↵- u-neck↵- long sleeves↵- loose fit↵- knee hemline↵- plain print"`

```
val.split(/(?:([\.,?;\n])\s?)/gi)
```

My current result is like this

`["always on the go", "?", "if yes", ",", "slip-on this dress that comes with u-neck", ",", "long sleeves and loose fit", ".", "wear with slacks and beanie to finish the ensemble", ".", "", "
", "- u-neck", "
", "- long sleeves", "
", "- loose fit", "
", "- knee hemline", "
", "- plain print"]`

But I want my result to be like this

```
array[0] = "always on the go?";
array[1] = "if yes,";
...
...
...
array[n] = '↵'
array[n] = '↵'
array[n] = '- u-neck'
...
...
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regular expression, it will keep your ,?. at the end of sentence.

```
var str= "always on the go? if yes, slip-on this dress that comes with u-         neck,long sleeves and loose fit. wear with slacks and beanie to finish the ensemble.↵↵- u-neck↵- long sleeves↵- loose fit↵- knee hemline↵- plain print".

var arr= str. split(/([^\.,?\n]+[\.,?\n])/gi);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is writing your own prototype

```
String.prototype.splitKeep = function(arr){
    if (!(arr instanceof Array)) throw('input array please');
    var value = this.toString();
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        value = value.split(arr[i]).join(arr[i] + ":split:").trim();
    }
    value = value.split(":split:");
    //remove all newlines with characters
    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++){
        var item = value[i];
        if (item[item.length-1] === '\n' && item.length > 1){
            value[i] = item.substring(0, item.length-1);
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

And to use this

```
str.splitKeep(['.', ',', '?', ';', '\n'])
```